# Interesting security demos for beginners

Tags: malware, xss, sql-injection, user-education

I am thinking about a creating short security demo to get people interested in the security topic. I've had a couple of ideas just want to see if anyone has anything else interesting.

Edit:

I was brought to my attention that this question is too broad and I will have to agree with this.

In order to narrow it down I will ask this instead:

 Can someone think of a simple "magic trick" or game that can be used to gather data for a very simple social engineering hack?

If people feel that this question is still to broad I will remove it. Thank you.

Comment: This is a subjective and broad question, not really suited for StackExchange.

Comment: I like your idea, but it's unfortunately not really suited for StackExchange's Q and A format.  You'd probably be better asking on a security forum.

Comment: While this may have the start of a "good subjective" question, I'm not sure it is quite tightly defined enough.  In particular, the audience is still fairly broad and the goal relatively wide.  Is there any way you might be able to narrow it down a bit?  For example, what kind of interest are you trying to inspire?

Comment: Hi guys. I think no matter how I tailor the question this will be too broad. Please mark as closed.

Answer (score 1):

I would demonstrate a simple SQL injection, it's always nice to see the look on people's faces when you attack a website with a browser as your only weapon.

Setup a simple site with a login page and then show them how you can expose the admins password by simply adding few characters to the url. After you get the admin's password delete the entire site. That will defiantly get them shocked